# Should every table in my database include store id?

Tags: database-design

I am designing single database for multiple stores. Every store may have different products and stock. should i have to include store_id in every table in database. my database looks like this [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Composite Primary Key in multi-tenant SQL Server database](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98118/composite-primary-key-in-multi-tenant-sql-server-database). If this Question does pertain to Microsoft SQL Server, then please see my answer to that Question for additional considerations (in addition to what @Remus has [suggested](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140725/30859)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is called multi-tenancy. You want to offer the database service to multiple 'tenants' (in your case, stores). Microsoft published some time ago a paper on the topic, [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) which highlights some approaches (separate database, shared database separate schemas, shared tables) with pros and cons of each. Your approach is shared tables, and yes, you do need a store_id in table that contain per-store data (there are usually some shared tables that do no require a `store_id`). Not only that, but all indexes will require `store_id` as a leftmost key. All your JOIN must also add `AND left.store_id = right.store_id` as a join condition. And all your queries must have a `WHERE store_id=@store_id` filter.

Answer (score 0):

If those stores are totally independent  and the only reason to have them in a single databases is to share stored procs, etc then add store id to every table. But think of some possible future development. Can different stores share some product definitions? Will there be transactions referencing different stores at once? Probably you need more elaborate design.