# Is it good practice to have relationship between the tenant table and all other tables in a multi tenant application?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, multi-tenant, azure-sql-database

I am developing a multi tenant SaaS that uses Azure SQL for data storage. I make use of sp_set_session_context to make sure that any query only touches records relevant to the current tenant.

I occationally get requests to delete a tenant from the database. That means the record in the Tenants table and all other records in other tables with the same Tenant_Id. Today I do this with one DELETE statement per table.

Is it a good idea to create a relationship between Tenant and all other tables? This way I could use cascade delete to delete a tenant by simply removing a single record from the tenants table.

I am concerned about the more difficult recovery in the case of a mistakenly deleted tenant. I also want to be confident that there will be no serious performance issues with such a schema.

Comment: Note that this is one of _many_ reasons to use a separate database for each tenant.  In Azure SQL Database, you can use Elastic Pools to host the tenant databases.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool

Answer (score 0):

1. > Is it a good idea to create a relationship between Tenant and all other tables?

   Yes. Absolutely yes, you should have a relationship between them physically (it is already there logically).
2. > This way I could use cascade delete to delete a tenant by simply removing a single record from the tenants table.

   Er, um, not so sure about this one. Depending on the size / complexity of your schema, you might not be able to do this anyway due to potential circular references. I would do cascading delete FKs for subsets of tables that together act as a particular feature or property. But I don't see this as a good thing for doing over the entire schema, even if you don't get circular reference errors. Still, adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` to subsets of tables will at least reduce the total number of delete statements (although, you should already be doing the `DELETE`s in a transaction, so transactionally this won't really be any different; it will be fewer `DELETE` statements for you to code / maintain, though the main benefit will be helping to ensure integrity within those subsets).

For more info, please see my answer, here on DBA.SE, to the following question:

[Composite Primary Key in multi-tenant SQL Server database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119700/30859)